How to resolve ##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : [ '' ] error?
Any suggestions on how to resolve this pipeline error below to build and deploy a Web API?
It's failing on the Generate OpenAPI definition for ${{ parameters.DocumentName }} step and the error implies it doesn't know about any projects?
.yaml file:
parameters:

- name: ApiFileName
  displayName: 'API Definition file name'
  default: 'swagger.json'
  type: string

- name: DocumentName
  displayName: 'Name of the openapi document to extract'
  type: string

steps:
 - task: ExtractFiles@1
   displayName: 'Extract Artifact'
   inputs:
    archiveFilePatterns: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.zip' 
    destinationFolder: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\unzipped_artifact\

 - task: UseDotNet@2
   displayName: 'Force Net 6.0 usage'
   inputs:
     version: '6.x'
 
 - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
   displayName: 'Tool Manifest'
   inputs:
     command: 'custom'
     custom: 'new'
     arguments: 'tool-manifest'

 - task: PowerShell@2
   displayName: 'Setup CLI tool and variables'
   inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
        mkdir $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\openapi_specs\
        $version = (Get-Item $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\unzipped_artifact\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.dll).VersionInfo.FileVersionRaw
        $versionstring = "{0}.{1}.{2}" -f $version.Major,$version.Minor,$version.Build
        $exeName = (Get-ChildItem -Path $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\unzipped_artifact\ -Filter *.exe |Select BaseName).BaseName + ".dll"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SwaggerToolVersion;]$versionstring"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ApiStartupName;]$exeName"
        Write-Host "Setting tool version to found Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger version '$versionstring' and API startup DLL to '$exeName'"

 - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
   displayName: 'Install Swagger CLI'
   inputs:
     command: 'custom'
     custom: 'tool'
     arguments: 'install Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli --version $(SwaggerToolVersion)'

 - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
   displayName: 'Generate OpenAPI definition for ${{ parameters.DocumentName }}'
   inputs:
     command: 'custom'
     custom: 'swagger'
     arguments: 'tofile --output $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\openapi_specs\${{ parameters.ApiFileName }} $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\unzipped_artifact\$(ApiStartupName) ${{ parameters.DocumentName }}'

 - task: CopyFiles@2
   displayName: 'Copy API Definition to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
   inputs:
     SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/openapi_specs/'
     Contents: '*.json'
     TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
     flattenFolders: true

 - template: /Pack&Publish/PackageAPIDefForOctopus.yaml
   parameters:
     APIDefinitionPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/openapi_specs/'

Error:
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe swagger tofile --output D:\a\1\s\openapi_specs\swagger.json D:\a\1\s\unzipped_artifact\Returns.API.dll Returns API
Usage: dotnet swagger tofile [options] [startupassembly] [swaggerdoc]

startupassembly:
  relative path to the application's startup assembly

swaggerdoc:
  name of the swagger doc you want to retrieve, as configured in your startup class

options:
  --output:  relative path where the Swagger will be output, defaults to stdout
  --host:  a specific host to include in the Swagger output
  --basepath:  a specific basePath to include in the Swagger output
  --serializeasv2:  output Swagger in the V2 format rather than V3
  --yaml:  exports swagger in a yaml format


##[debug]Exit code 1 received from tool 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe'
##[debug]STDIO streams have closed for tool 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe'
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Error: The process 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
Info: Azure Pipelines hosted agents have been updated and now contain .Net 5.x SDK/Runtime along with the older .Net Core version which are currently lts. Unless you have locked down a SDK version for your project(s), 5.x SDK might be picked up which might have breaking behavior as compared to previous versions. You can learn more about the breaking changes here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/ and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/ . To learn about more such changes and troubleshoot, refer here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : [ '' ]
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : [ '' ]
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : [ '' ]


From the current pipeline definition, it seemed that there was no default value for ${{ parameters.DocumentName }}, Did you pass any value when running this pipeline? From the logs it seemed to expaned as Returns API, there was a space which could have caused the dotnet CLI failed.

@AlvinZhao-MSFT Yes, it was passed like so 'Returns API'

Would you give a try to double quote the value like "${{ parameters.DocumentName }}" in the arguments of the dotnet swagger tofile step?

As stated in the documentation, the last part of the command is swaggerdoc.
swagger tofile --output [output] [startupassembly] [swaggerdoc]

[output] is the relative path where the Swagger JSON will be output to
[startupassembly] is the relative path to your application's startup
assembly
[swaggerdoc] is the name of the swagger document you want to retrieve,
as configured in your startup class

It should be the same as defined in your config.SwaggerDoc, e.g. v1 or v2.
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API - V1", Version = "v1" });
    c.SwaggerDoc("v2", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API - V2", Version = "v2" });
})

See here or here for more details.

The Title property of my SwaggerDoc is "Returns API".

Try "${{ parameters.DocumentName }}" as suggested by @alvin

@Bhav The value of the parameter should not be value of Title, but rather the first argument of SwaggerDoc("v1", ... (the first string)

Based on the discussions, we could see the value of Returns API was passed in the pipeline for the ${{ parameters.DocumentName }}. Since there was a space in the dotnet swagger tofile command arguments, it had the dotnet CLI failed with incorrect usage error. Here was the issue I could reproduce.

For this, I double quoted the "${{ parameters.DocumentName }}" to be passed as a whole argument; however, even having double quoted the "${{ parameters.DocumentName }}", it was not a valid argument to me.
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Generate OpenAPI definition for ${{ parameters.DocumentName }}'
    inputs:
      command: 'custom'
      custom: 'swagger'
      arguments: 'tofile --output $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\openapi_specs\${{ parameters.ApiFileName }} $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\unzipped_artifact\$(ApiStartupName) "${{ parameters.DocumentName }}"'



Based on the answer by @DaST, it seemed to be the usage issue of swagger command rather than your pipeline. Having tested to pass the value v1, it was working.

    public static class SwaggerExtensions
    {
        public static void SaveSwaggerJson(this IServiceProvider provider)
        {
            ISwaggerProvider sw = provider.GetRequiredService<ISwaggerProvider>();
            OpenApiDocument doc = sw.GetSwagger("v1", null, "/");
            string swaggerFile = doc.SerializeAsJson(OpenApiSpecVersion.OpenApi3_0);

            // Get the bin folder path
            string binFolderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            string swaggerFilePath = Path.Combine(binFolderPath, "swaggerfile.json");

            // Save the Swagger JSON to the bin folder
            File.WriteAllText(swaggerFilePath, swaggerFile);
        }
    }


So I have to pass the value v2 as what parameter?

Hi @Bhav, Sorry for the mistyping. Per my 3rd screenshot, I passed v1 for the argument as we could see from the error message Known Swagger documents: "v1" in the second screenshot. I have shared my code snippet for your reference where the document v1 is defined. Therefore v1 is the valid swaggerdoc to me. We don't know what your project is like. You may first try and double quote the parameter to correct the usage error first. Hope the information helps.
